# Rates of Change: Maxima and Minima

Tags: calculus

How would I plug in $f(x)=\frac{2x+4}{x}$ into the formula $\frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$
I have to find the average rate of change between $x$ and $x+h$ for this function.

Is this solution correct? 
\begin{align}f(x+h)&=\frac{2(x+h)+4}{x+h} \\[2ex]
\frac{f(x+h)−f(x)}{h}&=\frac{2(x+h)+4}{x+h}−\frac{\frac{2x+4}{x}}{h} \\
&=\frac{−4x}{h+x}
\end{align}

Comment: Mathematical formulae look better in $\LaTeX$. [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020) is a quick tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a mistake, most probably when you were simplifying that expression, since it is $\frac{-4}{x(x+h)}$ and not $\frac{-4x}{x+h}$. You can also note that, $$f(x)=\dfrac{2x+4}{x}=\dfrac{2x}{x}+\dfrac{4}{x}=2+\dfrac{4}{x}.$$ When calculating $f(x+h)-f(x)$ the constant term $-$ in this case $2$ $-$ will vanish, and so we will be left with $$f(x+h)-f(x)=\dfrac{4}{x+h}-\dfrac4x=\dfrac{4x-4x-4h}{x(x+h)}=\dfrac{-4h}{x(x+h)},$$ Thus, $$\dfrac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\dfrac{-4}{x(x+h)}.$$